# Android: Loop to pick a random images from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, random

Right now my program randomly displays 5 random images from my Array List and here's the main part of what I have now:

```
int myImgCount;
int totalImgCount;
int[] array1;

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Random r = new Random();

    int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five };

    int totalImgCount = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++)
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            int myImgCount = r.nextInt(5);

                 totalImgCount += myImgCount + 1;

            if (totalImgCount<50) {

                list.add(images[myImgCount]);   //do it again if not yet at 50
                break;
            }
                   totalImgCount -= (myImgCount + 1);
        }


    }

    array1 = convertIntegers(list);

}

public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers) {
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I'm now getting an error in my render method here that is causing the app to crash:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {

    if (canvas != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Start Random");
        Random random = new Random();
        canvas.drawRGB(234, 237, 235);

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), array1[i]);            
       // ^This is where I am now getting an error that is causing the app to crash 

          canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-bmp.getWidth
                      ()), random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-bmp.getHeight()),null);

        }

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make each drawable image have an integer value such as: R.drawable.one equal to 1, R.drawable.two equal to 2.....R.drawable.five equal to 5.

And have a loop repeat until the images displayed equals a total value of 50 (they all add up to 50) and then stop.

I'm trying to get myImgCount and totalImgCount to keep track of the value of the image that is randomly chosen and I know it isn't right but I can't find any info on how to complete this task. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help, I'm new to coding so if you can explain why you used your code it would help even more! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the drawable naming convention as R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2 and use

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
  a[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("image"+(i+1), "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

Details on `getIdentifier` method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

Hope this helps

Comment: My question might not have been clear enough or I may be misunderstanding your solution but I wasn't asking about the image names. I'm trying to create a 'for' loop that displays images until the total is 50. and I'm trying to do this by giving each image in my array a value. I really appreciate the response though!

Comment: So, you have only 5 images right? Sorry for misunderstanding your question... So you want to display images until the total exceeds 50, right?

Comment: Yeah just 5 images: R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, and R.drawable.five  and I want them to have an int value the same as their name. So for example: R.drawable.one will have a int value of 1. Then I want my loop to run and display random images until the total is 50. And I was trying to use myImgCount to keep track of the total but I couldn't get it to work. Hope that helps! Thanks again!